.NET8 upgrade PostAsync One or more errors occurred.(Input string was not in a correct format. Failure to parse near offset 2. Expected an ASCII digit
string Request = "{\"serviceKey\":\"100227327603613784\",\"notificationMessageData\":{\"messageId\":463979,\"cardAcceptorName\":\"REPUBLIC SERVICES\",\"cardAcceptorCountryCode\":\"US\",\"cardAcceptorCity\":\"PHOENIX\",\"transactionCurrencyCode\":\"840\",\"transactionAmount\":\"3500.00\",\"transactionMinorUnit\":\"2\",\"transactionType\":\"Declined\",\"triggerTypeCode\":\"ACCB\"}}"

string url = "https://Server:8440/Services/Processor/api/v1/send"

var responseMessage = Client.PostAsync(url , new StringContent(Request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;


Exception Message: One or more errors occurred. (Input string was not in a correct format. Failure to parse near offset 2. Expected an ASCII digit.)"

Note: There is no code changes, only after .NET8 upgrade this issue come. if downgraded it will work fine
Expected is HttpClient PostAsync should work, but it is not even calling the other service

Can you please provide a full [mre]?
